# Office 365 Rest API : Restrict access to specific mailbox

Tags: office365api

Within Azure AD, we setup an application to provide access to mailboxes through API. This works.
However, I'd like to know if there is a way to restrict such access to specific mailboxes only ?
From the Microsoft interface, it looks like we can only set permissions at a whole level...

I hope this question has not been answered yet (I did a search first), but I am new on this board so pardon me if I am wrong :)

Thanks and have a good day,
Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

This is true and today app-only access cannot be scoped to a particular mailbox. Can you please share your thoughts on User Voice. https://officespdev.uservoice.com, so that the product team can prioritize this and add it to their list of work items.